# Is it rude to say "foolishly wrong"?

Tags: translation, formal-language

Is it rude to say

> "If you thought it, then you'd be **foolishly wrong**!"

?

Especially regarding the formal or semi-formal format of speech.
When I searched for a translation into my language (Russian), one source said that it means something like "very wrong". Is it so?

Comment: Yes, it's rude. Look up "fool" in the dictionary. It may be fitting, but it is rude.

Comment: I should have added that "foolishly" is an adverb derived from the word "foolish", which is an adjective derived from the word "fool".

Comment: This is an insult, and as such, it's rude.